# Understanding props of a wrapped component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am confused about the export magic in the following code from [this tutorial](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-setup-firebase-authentication-with-react-in-5-minutes-maybe-10-bb8bb53e8834) (available at [GitHub](https://github.com/armand1m/react-firebase-authentication-medium)):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withFirebaseAuth from 'react-with-firebase-auth'
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    
    const {
      user,
      signOut,
      signInWithGoogle,
    } = this.props;

    if (user) {
      console.log(user.uid);
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          {
            user
              ? <p>Hello, {user.displayName}</p>
              : <p>Please sign in.</p>
          }

          {
            user
              ? <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
              : <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign in with Google</button>
          }
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const firebaseAppAuth = firebaseApp.auth();

const providers = {
  googleProvider: new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(),
};

export default withFirebaseAuth({
  providers,
  firebaseAppAuth,
})(App);
```

I do not understand (1) how come `App.props` has new members and (2) how come these new members are not undefined at the beginning of `App.render()`. In more detail:

1. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/armand1m/react-with-firebase-auth/blob/master/README.md), I understand that the call to `withFireBaseAuth()` in `export` returns a function, which, when called with `App` as an argument, returns a component. However, it is a new component. So, how come `props` get added to `App`?
2. The call to `withFireBaseAuth()` appears **after** the definition of `App`, so how come `App.props.user` is not undefined when it is used in `App.render()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. According to the documentation, I understand that the call to withFireBaseAuth() in export returns a function, which, when called
>    with App as an argument, returns a component. However, it is a new
>    component. So, how come props get added to App?

`withFirebaseAuth` is a [Higher Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), which is really just a specialized [higher order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) that consumes a React component, imbues it with extra behavior (props, etc...) and returns a new Component.

A very simple HOC may look like this:

```
const withMyHOC = Component => props => (
  <Component {...props} extraProp="extraProp" />
);
```

and to use, `const MyComponentWithExtraProp = withMyHOC(MyComponent);`.

The trick here is that HOCs return React components, i.e. they receive `props`, and then pass them forward (spread operator) to the component being decorated.

HOCs can also be written to take additional arguments.

```
const withMyHOC = (arg1, arg2) => Component => props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('rendered', arg2);
  });
  return (
    <Component {...props} extraProp="extraProp" arg={arg1} />
  )
};
```

and to use, `const MyComponentWithExtraProp = withMyHOC("test")(MyComponent);`.

`withFirebaseAuth` appears to take a configuration argument, create the auth provider, and inject `user`, `signOut`, and `signInWithGoogle` as props into the component being decorated, e.g. `App`.

> 2. The call to withFireBaseAuth() appears after the definition of App, so how come App.props.user is not undefined when it is used in
>    App.render()?

Remember, these are ***just*** the component declarations. `App` component is declared in the file, and then decorated with `withFirebaseAuth` and then default exported.

```
export default withFirebaseAuth({
  providers,
  firebaseAppAuth,
})(App);
```

Elsewhere `App` (really the decorated one) is default imported and rendered by React.

```
import App from '../path/to/app';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Notice here that we don't need to pass any props, but that `user`, `signOut`, and `signInWithGoogle` will be injected by `withFirebaseAuth`.